# Create SQL Server Side Logon Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am having an error on creating a logon trigger.

> logon failed for login due to trigger

Please explain the mistakes I am doing in this query please.

```
 CREATE TABLE LoginAudit (
            LoginAuditID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
            EventType NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            LoginName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            HostName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            ApplicationName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            LogonTime DATETIME NOT NULL
        );
        
        CREATE TRIGGER AuditLogins
        ON ALL SERVER
        FOR LOGON
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @EventData xml
            SET @EventData = EVENTDATA()
            INSERT INTO LoginAudit (EventType, LoginName, HostName, ApplicationName, LogonTime)
            VALUES (@EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'),
                    @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'),
                    @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/HostName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'),
                    @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ApplicationName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'),
                    GETDATE())
        END;
        GO
```

Comment: Have you setup a Profiler or Extended event to catch the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I added your trigger to my machine, and set up a trace I got the following error:

[image]

The `EVENTDATA()`. When I look into the EVENTDATE() response on my machine, it does not return the HostName and ApplicationName:

```
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>LOGON</EventType>
  <PostTime>2023-03-02T08:53:58.047</PostTime>
  <SPID>78</SPID>
  <ServerName>XXXXX</ServerName>
  <LoginName>db_owner_with_agent</LoginName>
  <LoginType>SQL Login</LoginType>
  <SID>XXXX</SID>
  <ClientHost>&lt;local machine&gt;</ClientHost>
  <IsPooled>0</IsPooled>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>
```

So it looks like you need to alter your table to remove those columns, or make them NULL. Or find another way to fetch those values. For example you might fetch it based on the SID provided in the XML above:

```
SELECT hostname, s.program_name FROM sys.sysprocesses AS s
WHERE s.spid = @yourspid
```

How to retrieve the error:

- Check the SQL Error logs
- Set up Extended Event (or profiler) to catch the error occuring

**Error logs**
[image]

Then you can find the exact error.
[image]

**Extended Event**
I set ext. event below (You might don't want to use this one on production ;-) )

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [CatchErrors] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlos.exception_ring_buffer_recorded(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.attention(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.errorlog_written(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id))
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

You can find your extended events:
[image]

Start it, watch live data, do your repro steps and see the data popping in :)

[image]

For more information about Ext. Events:
https://www.scarydba.com/2020/03/16/extended-events-live-data-explorer-getting-started/

Comment: Awesome its working after making null able  column.  Sir May I Ask in Which Matchin u put this Code  got this Error. Can you Explain us.   Is it  debugging or what?

Comment: Sure! I'll add it to the answer ;)

Comment: Yes. HostName Application Column are Null.  but I am just using this code to keep eyes on Student that who login to MsSQL.

Comment: Has been added :)